# Question about application of the theorem of Poincaré Bendixson in a field gradient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open one and $X: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a  gradient vector field  of class
$C^1$ with an amount (without an enumerable number of singularities).
Given a trajectory $\psi(.; p)$ whose domain contains $\mathbb{R}^+$, show that $\omega (p)$
or is empty or is a unitary set.

The set $\omega (p)$ is : $\omega (p)=$ {$ q \in U; \exists \,\,\,\ \{ t_n \}; n \rightarrow \infty  \Rightarrow ( t_n) \rightarrow \infty; \,\,\, \psi(t_n)=q $    }.

I'm trying to use the Poincaré Bendixson Theorem, but apparently it's not straightforward, because I need more hypotheses, for example, that the positive half-orbit was contained in a compact subset of $U$. I have tested many ways, but none seems to be correct . Someone can help!

Comment: Check again the definition, you should find that $ψ(t_n;p)\to q$ is demanded, $q$ is a limit point of the trajectory through $p$, not just a repeating value.

Comment: Please, try using the correct English terminology: not "field gradient" but "gradient vector field", not "unitary set" but "singleton" (as far as I can gather your intentions).

Comment: More to the point: The Poincaré-Bendixson theorem can be applied to planar vector fields only (or to vector fields on some two-dimensional manifolds, such as sphere).

Answer (score 1):

As a gradient field, there is some function $f\in C^2$ so that $X=\nabla f$. Then for any solution $x$ of $\dot x=X(x)$ one has per chain rule
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f(x(t))=f'(x(t))\dot x(t)=\|\nabla f(x(t))\|^2
$$
so that the value of $f$ is monotonically increasing along $f$. Now use that to conclude the claim on the $ω$ set.